# Java Script onclick multiple Validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
 <html:submit 
    property   = "buttonClicked"
    styleClass = "buttonEnabled"  
    value      = " Search"
    onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Searching'"
    onclick="return rfqValidation();"/>
```

This is my validation on the button click. 
But only one validation is working.
If I give together it is  Validating but after that form is submitting as I have given this.form.submit().
Any suggestion please so that both works with html:submit.

Comment: I'd suggest you write everything in one function and call it on html.

Comment: Thank you @rajesh it helped.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajesh is right

or do it in a single onclick. I think you can not have multiple onclick in single tag.

```
<html:submit 
property   = "buttonClicked"
styleClass = "buttonEnabled"  
value      = " Search"
onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Searching';return rfqValidation();"/>
```

Comment: Also reason why I suggested to put it under one function is because your html becomes cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick property returns the click event handler code on the current element. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

So, when you do the second `onclick` assignment operation, a new anonymous function gets assigned to the `onclick` property. So, you have to wrap them up in the same function call.